# Object doesn't support this property/method in an IF statement within a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is used to organize daily orders for many customers into one sheet. The information that is entered into this sheet is then used to generate invoices for the customers.
This workbook has worked without any bugs for several months. However, recently it has started throwing up an error. I do not recall changing any of the code that could have caused this bug.

I have tried to figure this out by myself however, I am running out of ideas, here are a few things that I have found out:

- The error ALWAYS pops up on the 7th iteration of the loop below (i.e when x=27).
- The error ONLY has a problem with the `(CheckBox " & x + 10)` checkbox. I have tried running the loop avoiding checking the value of that particular checkbox and it works for all other checkboxes.
- I read on another post that it might be a problem with using the dreaded `.Select`. So I got rid of it from everywhere that it might have been used.

My code

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice")
For x = 21 To 35
    If .Shapes("Check Box " & x + 10).ControlFormat.Value = 1 And .Shapes("Check Box " & x + 25).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please only select one from the options (Return OR Discount)"
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
Next x
End With
```

From what I understand, this error comes up when the object that I am working with does not support a property that I am trying to work with. What I do not understand is why the same lines of code, work "for 90%" of the loop (i.e the same type of object does support that property for 90% of the loop) but then it does not for one object of the same type.

For completeness, the code below is used to re-insert the checkboxes every time the workbook is used. This is done as another process might delete entire rows in the workbook, messing up the functionality of the check-boxes. So this makes sure the checkbox with the right name is in the correct cell:

```
Sub CheckBoxes()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").CheckBoxes.Delete
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice")

    For x = 5 To 19
    Set cb = .CheckBoxes.Add(.Cells(x, "J").Left, .Cells(x, "J").Top, 4, 10)

    With cb
        .Name = "Check Box " & x + 26
        .Caption = ""
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With

    Set cb2 = .CheckBoxes.Add(.Cells(x, "K").Left, .Cells(x, "K").Top, 4, 10)

    With cb2
        .Name = "Check Box " & x + 41
        .Caption = ""
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With

    Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

**Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Both sets of code work fine for me - I would suspect you have some random (non-checkbox) object on your sheet which is left over from debugging etc, and this is interfering with the code.  Is this reproducible on a fresh sheet?

Comment: To be clear, you *do* have a shape named `Check Box 37`, yeah?

Comment: Yes, there is a shape named `Check Box 37`

Comment: I have deleted all objects within the sheet and re-ran the code. It now works! I cannot believe it was that simple. The only other object that I can think of that is on the sheet is a button. In what way can other objects interfere with the code?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook with the macro that is also the one with the shapes, right? What happens if you refer to the workbook by name?

Comment: It's possible for two shapes on the same sheet to share the same name - that's when your problems begin...